# How to unselect selected option in md-select Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In material2 when a select is initialized no default value is selected. If user selects a value he can't unselect it. I want to enable the user to unselect the value.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/KQz2cHQ9Nzj6YtcXQ5jo?p=preview)

I went through the [help already available](https://material.angular.io/components/component/select) but wasn't able to use it.

```
<mat-select id="formal"  formControlName="formal" placeholder="Default - No value selected">
   <mat-option value="1">formal</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="2">informal</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ended up using ngModel and setting that value to undefined to get the required result.

```
<md-select id="formal" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" formControlName="formal" placeholder="Default - No value selected">
    <md-option value="1">formal</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">informal</md-option>
 </md-select>

<div  (click)="unselect()">click me to clear md select</div>
```

In the Component

```
unselect(): void {
   this.selectedValue = undefined;
}
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kkYbNt9UJ2iKxOhIPcq8?p=preview) for the answer.

Comment: plunkr link is boken

Comment: This shouldn't be accepted answer. Use of ngModel is pointless and unnecessary, since angular forms do have the value

Comment: What if you're not using a form?

Comment: Hi Mahin, can we do the same thing without using a buton or without using a click event

Answer (score 32):

What about using a method of matSelect.

```html
<mat-select (selectionChange)="onChange($event)">
```

```js
onChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
    const matSelect: MatSelect = event.source;
    matSelect.writeValue(null);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thx. Exactly what I was looking for. I'm using mat-select without angular forms.

Comment: Great answer - got my upvote! Especially because I failed to find a reference for this method in the docs https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: Please be aware that this changes the selection but doesn't change the `value` of select. As a result, the value will get selected when `options` are being updated. I did a simple `event.source.value = null` and it seems fine so far.

Answer (score 7):

I have another solution that I think worth to mention it: add an empty `<md-option>` and `reset` the `<md-select>` on its `click`

```
  <md-select id="formal" formControlName="formal" placeholder="Default - No value selected">
      <md-option (click)="form.controls.formal.reset()"></md-option>
      <md-option value="1">formal</md-option>
      <md-option value="2">informal</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

this way you don't need any custom code in your `Component` neither use `ngModel`

see [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/de28EbYTVakfnkAT8dv4?p=preview)

Comment: It still selects something in this case and empty value. I was looking for that completely sets it to default state.

Comment: in a regular html `select` you don't have this option either...you need to create a empty `option` or a '-- select something --' `option` to have a "default state".  This way is better for UI as the user has the option to select nothing instead of click in a button but I don't know your user case. ;-)

Comment: plunkr link is boken

Comment: probably because of old version of angular/material but idea still the same

Comment: its helpful to note that using click event of empty option we could even clear value

Answer (score 3):

If you are using angular forms, you can always `patchValue` to `''` as like below.

First, the select element. This example is using Ionic, but it's the same as Angular.

```
<ion-select formControlName="formal" item-start>
   <ion-option *ngFor="let option of input.options" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>

<ion-icon color="danger" name="close" (click)="unselect('formal')" item-end></ion-icon>
```

Where `form` is a `FormGroup`.

```
  form: FormGroup;
```

And the `unselect` method patches a null value.

```
  unselect(id: string): void {
    let reset = {};
    reset[id] = ''
    this.form.patchValue(reset);
  }
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Deal</mat-label>
            <mat-select>
              <mat-option>None</mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let object of somelist" [value]="object">{{object.property}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: FYI: instead of "None" you can use it with any keyword.

Answer (score 2):

a bit late but I just add an option as the first one to allow the user to clear the dropdownlist

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Parent Organisation" [formControl]="form.controls['parentOrganisationId']">
        <mat-option *ngIf="form.controls['parentOrganisationId'].value" [value]="null">Clear</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of organisations$ | async" [value]="option.id">
          {{ option.description }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a select with reset option:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>State</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Reference from [Angular material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples).

Answer (score 1):

For me, work this way in mat-select:

in HTML:

```
  <mat-form-field class="input-withd-columns-total">
          <mat-label>Ação</mat-label>
          <mat-select #action1>
            <mat-option>{{ viewValue }}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

in TS:

```
@ViewChild("action1") action1: MatSelect;
this.action1.value = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the accepted answer to **Angular 6**:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select id="formal" [(value)]="selectedValue"  placeholder="Default - No value selected">
        <mat-option value="1">formal</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">informal</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div  (click)="selectedValue = null">click me to clear md select</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I develop this work around (I'm working with forms too so...), setting the value to undefined to reset the mat-select.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Add roles</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="rolesFormCtrlStepper3" (selectionChange)="createRole($event.value)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let roleComboBox of rolesComboBox" [value]="roleComboBox">
                             {{roleComboBox}}
                </mat-option>
           </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
createRole(r) {
...
...
    this.formArray.get([2]).get('rolesFormCtrlStepper3').setValue(undefined);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me here, in the end went into a deep hack in the change handler which I feel is unfortunate, but for me, necessary.

```
@ViewChild('matSelect') matSelect;

...

(this.matSelect.options as any)._results.forEach(opt => opt._selected = false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice how "--Remove--" does not have a value... when that is selected it will unset any value from before

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>{{facet._id}}<span class="red bold" *ngIf="facet.active">*</span></mat-label>
    <mat-select [ngModel]="facet.active" (selectionChange)="filter.emit([{filter: facet._id, option: $event.source.value}, false])" name="Sort">
      <mat-option>-- Remove --</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of facet.option" [value]="item.value">
          {{item.value}}
          <span>({{item.count}})</span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can simply access to options and use 'deselect' method.

**Html:**

```
<mat-select #select multiple>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let neighborhood of neighborhoods" [value]="neighborhood">
            {{neighborhood.name}}
          </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Ts:**

```
@ViewChild('select') select: MatSelect;

deselect(value){
   this.select.options.find(option => option.value === value)?.deselect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this for higher versions of angular there's a simple way provided in material docs. You just need to specify an option without a value which essentially sets whatever you have mapped it to as null. Unfortunately there isn't an inbuilt cancel button provided which would've been more convenient but this also works well.

```
      <mat-select>
         <mat-option>None</mat-option>
         <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" 
         [value]="option.value">
           {{option.label}}
         </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

Link for reference : https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#resetting-the-select-value